# Pass QMetaMethod as parameter to a function that uses the new QObject::connect syntax

Tags: c++, qt

I want to kinda build a wrapper around QObject's connect using the new syntax that has type check at compilation time.
The main idea would be: "hey listener, connect this object's slots to my newData signal"

```
void Listener::_addClient(const QObject *object, const QMetaMethod& slot)
{
    connect(this, &Listener::newData, object, slot);
}
```

And some `Client` class would simply do:

```
Listener myListener;
myListener._addClient(this, &Client::mySlot);
```

This of course does not compile.

- Since all `Listener` objects will be owned by a manager class, I cannot access them directly, so its not possible to do the traditional connect.

How can I build a wrapper for this connect so I can assure the type check at compilation time?

Answer (score 0):

You might use template:

```
template <typename Receiver, typename Slot>
void Listener::_addClient(const Receiver *object, const Slot& slot)
{
    connect(this, &Listener::newData, object, slot);
}
```

Comment: When calling it I get: error: static assertion failed: Signal and slot arguments are not compatible.

Comment: Which are the signatures of `Listener::newData` and `&Client::mySlot`?

Answer (score 0):

I could not make Jarod42 solution work because I needed access to protected properties and the method needed to be public.

I ended up proceeding as follow

```
void Listener::_addClient(const QObject *receiver, const char *slot)
{
        connect(this, SIGNAL(newData()), receiver, slot);
}
```

calling like so

```
Listener myListener;
myListener._addClient(this, SLOT(mySlot()));
```

It might not be the pretiest way to proceed but it works.